# Como saltar el rate limit, Twitter Tweepy Python

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-api, tweepy

he hecho un pequeño script, que hace muchas request, debido a que monitorea cuentas de Twitter, el problema es que al minuto de estar funcionando salta el rate limit de la página, quisiera saber de qué manera puedo conseguir saltar esto, he estado investigando por medio de proxys etc.. Pero no me queda nada claro. Gracias de antemano
Dejo un pequeño código a modo de ejemplo, a ese código habría que añadirle los hilos para que se ejecutará concurrentmente con más usuarios, por lo que serían más request.

```
import tweepy
import configparser
from datetime import datetime

def apiTwitter(): #Para conectarse a twitter y scrapear con su api, devuelve objeto de tweepy cheto para scrapear twitter
    # read credentials
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('credentialsTwitter.ini')

    api_key = config['twitter']['api_key']
    api_key_secret = config['twitter']['api_key_secret']

    access_token = config['twitter']['access_token']
    access_token_secret = config['twitter']['access_token_secret']

    # authentication
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key,api_key_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)

    api=tweepy.API(auth)

    return api


api=apiTwitter() #Con api ahora podemos scrapear todo twitter de forma sencilla
While True:
 tweets =     api.user_timeline(screen_name='kowaals ki_',tweet_mode="extended", count=1)
 tweet=tweets[0]
 #print(tweet._json)
 print(f'Tweet text: 
 {tweet.full_text}')
 time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Da igual que uses threads; lo que cuenta es la *IP de la máquina* desde donde sale el *request*.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente estas superando el límite de request por minuto y/o por segundo, este es bien bajo (en cuentas gratis es de 30 request por minuto y 10 request por segundo) y hay un límite de 100 tweets por request. Una solución es programar límites de descarga para que el programa no se caiga al llegar al límite y que haga un nuevo request al minuto siguiente (por ejemplo, un while con un time sleep al final, en tu caso partiría fijando el time.sleep(1) en time.sleep(60)). Esto creo que sería la mejor opción. Otra opción serían pagar más. Toda mi respuesta es teórica ya que solo he usado la api de twitter en tareas de estudio muy acotadas por lo que cualquier otro aporte es muy bienvenido. Espero que te sirva

Comment: Holaa @Juan Eduardo Grez, muchas gracias, aunque ajuste los límites, al estar monitoreando por ejemplo 10 cuentas de Twitter, no me es factible, creo que la única solución es pagar más, ¿Sabes como hacer para que me desbloqueen más request por minutos, aunque haya que pagar?

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que revises la página de desarrolladores de Twitter, ahí está toda la información, espero que te sirva